# RDLC flow layout table

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc

How can I create a table in RDLC (VS2013) that has 4 columns with dynamic rows ?

This is my datatable

[image]

I need to get something like this, 4 product for every rows.

[image]

I've already tried with a matrix but I can't find a way to limit the column group to 4.